# Combine multiple regular expressions into one

Tags: python, regex

i have this variable:

```
Application name: Clarion.Pricing.Grid.Service^
Source: EC2AMAZ-ITEJKDI
Timestamp: 2019-01-21T03:52:01.798Z
Message: Connection id ""0HLJV4AI9OCV6"", Request id ""0HLJV4AI9OCV6:000000=
08"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

and i want to get strings after Application name and Source, i'm not good with regex so i created 2 separate expressions:

```
regex1=r'Application name:\s*(.+?)\s+Source'
regex2=r'Source:\s*(.+?)\s+Timestamp:'    
a = re.findall(regex1 ,email_body) 
b = re.findall(regex2 ,email_body)
```

how to combine these 2 into one, and i need separate regex for returning string after Message

**desired output**

```
Clarion.Pricing.Grid.Service EC2AMAZ-ITEJKDI Connection id ""0HLJV4AI9OCV6"", Request id ""0HLJV4AI9OCV6:000000=
08"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:Application name:\s*(.+?)\s+(?=Source))|(?:Source:\s*(.+?)\s+(?=Timestamp:))
```

Explanation: you need to use positive lookahead `(?=` so that it doesn't consume the "Source" characters, or else it can't be detected by the second alternative, same for "Timestamp" by design even if it doesn't really matter here. The `(?:` are used to form groups of regexp that doesn't capture.

To add message, i assume you want to capture until the end of your input:

```
(?:Application name:\s*(.+?)\s+(?=Source))|(?:Source:\s*(.+?)\s+(?=Timestamp:))|(?:Message:\s*([\s\S]*)$)
```